# Time taken by bubble to come to surface

Tags: fluid-dynamics, acceleration, buoyancy, bubbles

Does air bubble take same time to emerge from shallow water and deep water? I think the acceleration due to buoyancy will be the cause.

Comment: I think you need to elaborate on why you think buoyancy will be the cause.\

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right, because if depth increased acceleration the bubbles from deep sea volcanic vents should be breaking the sound barrier on their way to the surface, but if you watch them on TV documentaries, they seem to ascend at the same rate as bubbles in much shallower water do. What is also noticeable is that the bubbles, whether in deep or shallow water, increase in size as they rise, but there is much more scope for this expansion in deep sea bubbles because they start at much greater pressure.

Comment: “I think you are right” means that you agree with the OP that bubbles take the “same *time*” to rise to the surface, regardless of whether they are coming from ten feet down or ten thousand feet down. That does not seem to be what you are arguing.

Comment: Will a bubble ascending from a greater depth tend to separate into smaller bubbles?

Comment: Yes, it will if it's a big one at the start..